# How to authenticate two types of user from oauth at the same time. and in every request header both users credential is needed

Tags: laravel, authentication, oauth, authorization, jwt

I have an agent authentication and there are lots of users under each agent. We want to authenticate with "Oauth" and with an app the agent can login beside an user. we want to login both (user and agent) from the same apps at the same time with "Oauth". What is the suitable way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one user table for storing user's info (username, password, ...) and you should authenticate based on this table, for many types of user you can use [plymorhipc-relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations), for example, you need three tables users, agents, regular_users and users table know type of each user.